# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'salaryNo'

Tags: java, class, exception, jstl, el

Kindly solve my problem of getting the distinct salaryNo

### PayrollController.java

```
public ModelAndView SalaryNoPopup(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)  {

   ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
   modelMap.addAttribute("GensalarystructureLst",payrollsystemdao.GensalarystructureList());
   return new ModelAndView("SalaryNoPopup", modelMap);
}
```

### PayrollDAO.java

```
public List<Gensalarystructure> GensalarystructureList(){

   List<Gensalarystructure> salary = null;
   Transaction tx=null;
   Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
    try
    {
      tx = session.beginTransaction();
      salary=session.createQuery(" select distinct salaryNo from Gensalarystructure " + " where status!='Inactive'").list();    
      tx.commit();
    }catch(HibernateException e){
    }finally{
      session.close();
    }
   return salary;
}
```

### SalaryNopopup.jsp

```
<tbody>
   <c:forEach items="${GensalarystructureLst}" var="salary">
   <tr>
     <td><c:out value="${salary.salaryNo}"/></td>

   </tr>
   </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

### Gensalarystructure.java

```
public class Gensalarystructure implements java.io.Serializable {
   private String salaryNo;
   private String status;
   public String getStatus() {
    return this.status;
   }

   public void setStatus(String status) {
     this.status = status;
   }
   public String getSalaryNo() {
    return this.salaryNo;
   }

   public void setSalaryNo(String salaryNo) {
    this.salaryNo = salaryNo;
   }
}
```

The problem here is **thePropertyNotFoundException**. Its not showing any values in the page.

Whenever I change the query as:

```
salary=session.createQuery("from Gensalarystructure " + "where status!='Inactive'").list();
```

Then its working absolutely fine. But I need the `salaryNo` into the sorted `format.so` I used the below query then it started throwing error.

```
salary=session.createQuery("select distinct salaryNo from Gensalarystructure " + " where status!='Inactive'").list();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## PayrollDAO.java ##

```
  public List<Gensalarystructure> GensalarystructureList(){

    System.out.println("SalaryList");
    List<Gensalarystructure[]> salary = null;
    Transaction tx = null;
    Gensalarystructure ob =null;
    Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Query query = null;
    List<Gensalarystructure> list = new ArrayList<Gensalarystructure>();
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
            query = session.createQuery("SELECT distinct salaryNo,userId FROM Gensalarystructure");      
            salary = query.list();
            System.out.println("list salary "+salary);                
              for(Object[] objArr: salary){
                        ob=new Gensalarystructure();
                        ob.setStructureNo(((String)(objArr[0])));
                        ob.setStructureCode((String)(objArr[1]));

                        list.add(ob);

                    }   

        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  finally {
        session.close();
    }

    return list;
}
```

hi guys, the salaryno property values are not identified so i have used the setter method to assign the property using iterator before sending the list object to JSTL view page.
afterthat JSTL can identified the particular  property AND it worked as expected.

Thank you all your support.
hope this answer helps .

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting only `List<String>` in your DAO

```
salary=session.createQuery(" select distinct salaryNo from Gensalarystructure "
+ " where status!='Inactive'").list();
```

change it to

```
Criteria criteria = (Criteria) session.
              createCriteria(Gensalarystructure.class).
criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("salaryNo")));
salary = criteria.list()
```

Comment: may i know what i need to change now?

Comment: Thanks for the reply..actually i need to select the distinct value of SalaryNo..thats why i am using that query.but end up in getting error

Comment: i am getting the same error after changing the code too..i coulnt able to identify the cause of the mistake

Comment: inspect the list it is being return, see what type of object it has, etc do some little debugging around it